# How to compute running sum if tag<>0 and reset to 0 if tag=0 in HIVE?

Tags: hive, conditional-statements, lag, cumulative-sum

```
customer    txn_date    tag running_sum
A           1-Jan-17    1   1
A           2-Jan-17    1   2
A           3-Jan-17    1   3
A           4-Jan-17    1   4
A           5-Jan-17    1   5
A           6-Jan-17    1   6
A           7-Jan-17    0   0
A           8-Jan-17    1   1
A           9-Jan-17    1   2
A           10-Jan-17   1   3
A           11-Jan-17   0   0
A           12-Jan-17   0   0
A           13-Jan-17   1   1
A           14-Jan-17   1   2
A           15-Jan-17   0   0
```

How to get the running_sum and and reset the running_sum to zero if tag=0? Just like on the sample above. TIA

Comment: Are you trying to write an SQL query? If yes, what have you tried already? See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create "groups" for each section of your 1s and 0s.  You can do this by creating a boolean flag and then cumulatively summing over that column to get groups.  From there you can cumulatively sum over your original `tag` column by each group you created in the sub-query.

**Query**:

```
SELECT customer
  , txn_date
  , tag
  , SUM(tag) OVER (PARTITION BY customer, flg_sum ORDER BY txn_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_sum
FROM (
  SELECT *
    , SUM(tag_flg) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY txn_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS flg_sum
  FROM (
    SELECT *
      , CASE WHEN  tag = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS tag_flg
    FROM database.table ) x ) y
```

**Output**:

```
customer        txn_date        tag     running_sum
A               2017-01-01      1       1
A               2017-01-02      1       2
A               2017-01-03      1       3
A               2017-01-04      1       4
A               2017-01-05      1       5
A               2017-01-06      1       6
A               2017-01-07      0       0
A               2017-01-08      1       1
A               2017-01-09      1       2
A               2017-01-10      1       3
A               2017-01-11      0       0
A               2017-01-12      0       0
A               2017-01-13      1       1
A               2017-01-14      1       2
A               2017-01-15      0       0
```

Comment: Thanks @gobrewers14! It worked! Actually, I'm exploring to use the lag and lead function on this but to no avail.